# Как заставить кнопку tkinter оставаться нажатой, пока другая не будет нажата?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Как один раз нажать на кнопку и чтобы она оставалась нажатой, пока не будет нажата другая кнопка?**

Comment: Кнопка на клавиатуре или кнопка в окне?

Comment: @insolor В окне

Comment: Встроенной такой функциональности у кнопок нет. Можно вместо кнопок использовать Radiobutton